# using a list of possible values in a switch command

Tags: r, switch-statement

Is it possible to provide a kind of list of possible values for my `switch` function. I would love to keep everything automatically updated, if someone provides a wrong parameter.

I use the `{}` for each condition, because I will execute more then just this variable declaration in my function, I will do several things within this switch.

```
switch(con,
       val1={
         filename <- 'SILAC-DML_with_PDF.R'
       },
       val2={
         filename <- 'SILAC-DML_with_PDF.R'
       },
       stop(sprintf('"%s" is an unknown condition type, please use one of "%s".\n',
                    con, paste(c('val1','val2'), collapse=', '))))
```

I would love to have something like a list where I can just paste the names to get the possible values. So the ideal solution would like a little bit like this, but without an error message :-)

```
my_list <- list(val1=filename <- 'a.R',
                val2=filename <- 'b.R')
switch(con,
       my_list,
       stop(sprintf('"%s" is an unknown condition type, please use one of "%s".\n',
                    con, names(my_list), collapse=', '))))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `switch` function is redundant, you can simply subset a list of values directly:

```
alternatives = list(val1 = 'SILAC-DML_with_PDF.R',
                    val2 = 'SILAC-DML_with_PDF.R')
result = alternatives[[con]]
if (is.null(result))
    stop(…)
```

… `switch` is an odd beast in R. I’ve never really found it useful.

If you require more complex actions to be performed, consider using a list of functions:

```
alternatives = list(
    val1 = function () { message('foo') },
    val2 = function () { message('bar') }
)

if (! con %in% names(alternatives))
    stop(…)
result = alternatives[[con]]()
```

I don’t think this can be smartly achieved with `switch` but it can of course be wrapped into its own little function. Note that unlike Hadley’s answer, all the above avoids partial argument name matching, which is a huge source of error and belongs banished from the face of the Earth.

Comment: At the moment I just define a variable within one of the conditions, but later in the script I will do more things within the switch, or this was at least my plan :-) This is why I used this strange structure, but your solution is also interesting.

Comment: @drmariod Ah, valid comment. In that case I’d suggest using a list of functions, and subsetting.

Comment: so just call the function within the list?! Hm, sounds like a solution I am looking  for... I updated my question a little bit.

Comment: I think this is perfect. No use for switch anymore! Didn't thought about these anonymous function within a list before. Perfect. You might rearrange you answer and put the list/function solution to the top. :-) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Instead of switch, you could use `match.arg()` and subsetting:

```
filenames <- c(
  val1 = "a.R",
  val2 = "b.R"
)
con <- match.arg(con, names(filenames))

filename <- filenames[[con]]
```

Note that this allows partial matching of `con`, which may or may not be helpful for your use case.

Comment: I updated my question a little bit. the filename thing was just a placeholder, I will do more commands within the switches.

Comment: Uh, my first answer by @hadley... I feel honoured :-)